# Unicode character isn't displayed as expected on iOS 9 (ok on iOS 8)

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

To get the symbol of the Armenian Dram, I do the following:

```
NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "hy_AM").objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) as! String
```

This gets me a square with a question mark inside while I should get the Armenian Dram symbol `Դ`.

If I try directly with the unicode symbol `\u{058F}` I get the same square with the question mark inside.

What's wrong?

EDIT:

It actually works fine on iOS 8 but doesn't on iOS 9.

Comment: The font you are using doesn't support that character. Use a different font.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I'm using `Helvetica`. I used `Verdana` as they say here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/058f/fontsupport.htm it supports the character but didn't work. I tried with a bunch of other font without success. Any universal font that could support all the different currencies symbols?

Comment: This is answered in the following question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363211/detect-when-a-unicode-character-cannot-be-displayed-correctly

Comment: @Nico excuse me, did you find the solution for your question?

Comment: @J.Koush Nop...