# Getting all available emojis on iOS version

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm currently attempting to get all the available emojis on an iOS device. The issue is that iOS 8.3 and iOS 9.1 both have new emojis which means that there will be some compatibility issues. My initial plan was to loop through the hex value ranges like so

```
for i in 0x1F601...0x1F64F {
    var c = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
    print(c)
}
```

The issue with this is that even an emoji is not supported on the device version, it will be displayed as a question mark when rendered on the device. I've spend some time searching around and I can't seem to find a good way to do such thing. What's the best way to get all the emojis on the device?

Comment: You need to check if a given font has a glyph for the character in question.

Comment: So from my understanding I could make a string of emojis, then check to see if the font has a glyph, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363211/detect-when-a-unicode-character-cannot-be-displayed-correctly). If it does, return the emoji, otherwise don't return it. Am I on the right track? @rmaddy

Comment: Good find. I was just closing your question as a duplicate of the very same question.