# In Java how to detect if a unicode image can be displayed in a JButton?

Tags: java, unicode

I found this Q&A : [Detect when a unicode character cannot be displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363211/detect-when-a-unicode-character-cannot-be-displayed-correctly)

But it's not in Java.

I have the following code :

```
int codePoint=Integer.parseInt(unicodeText,16);
byte eBytes[]=new String(Character.toChars(codePoint)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String str=new String(eBytes,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

JButton button=new JButton(str);
```

It can display unicode image on a JButton like this :

[image]

So if you set unicodeText to something like "1F602", it can display an image on a button.

My questions are :

<1> I tried both Java 8 and Java 12, result is the same, they are missing the same images from certain unicodes, why ? What can be done to make the missing images show up, seems Java upgrade didn't do it.

<2> How can I detect from my Java app which unicodes can't not be displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It depends on the font, so use [`Font::canDisplayUpTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo(java.lang.String))

So actually, grab your `Font` and try the following:

```
JButton button = new JButton(str);
Font font = button.getFont();
int failingIndex = font.canDisplayUpTo(str);
if (failingIndex >= 0) {
  // failingIndex points to the first codepoint in your string that cannot be represented with the font.
} else {
  // This string can be displayed with the given font.
}
```

So if the font cannot render the characters as expected, use another font that can.