# Specifying font fallbacks in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, opentype

I need to display text in a mixture of languages using the text-drawing functions in iOS. To make it concrete, let's say English and Malayalam. Malayalam (മലയാളം) is a beautifully curly language but hard to display right. It is usually best to use a specialist font which has been tuned to handle all its subtleties. So I might decide to use Caslon for English text, and Kartika for Malayalam.

Is there any way of telling iOS not only the font I want to use but the font it should fall back to, or am I reduced to analysing the text string, isolating "Malayalam-only" runs, and explicitly specifying Kartika for the Malayalam parts and Caslon for the English ones?

(Yes, I would of course license and embed Caslon and Kartika: this is not a question about font embedding but about font fallback specification).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Apple's text rendering draw a glyph that a font doesn't have?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069362/how-does-apples-text-rendering-draw-a-glyph-that-a-font-doesnt-have)

Comment: Yes, that question does seem to provide an answer that is worth testing, and I will test it.